# MATLAB: How to read data from a text file that have a certain character

Tags: matlab, file, text

I have a txt file, which contains a bunch of random data in two units, Distance (m) and Time (seconds). For example the `txt` file looks like this:

```
5 metre 

0 sec

10 metre

1 sec

16 metre

2 sec

25 metre

3 sec
```

I want to be able to store all of the `metres` values into an array, and the `seconds` data into another. Basically separating the text file into two arrays based on the metre/sec units.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [readtable](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html#btyaa8n-3)

I don't know whether this is the 'right' function, but this works :)

**Read Data:**

```
A = readtable('Input.txt','Delimiter',' ','ReadVariableNames',false);
```

Output would be something like this:

```
A = 

Var1     Var2  
____    _______

 5      'metre'
 0      'sec'  
10      'metre'
 1      'sec'  
16      'metre'
 2      'sec'  
25      'metre'
 3      'sec'
```

```
%// use 'cellfun' to create a mask of which unit corresponds to 'metre'
mask = cellfun(@(x) strcmp(x,'metre'), A.Var2);

%// save the corresponding data in one variable and rest in another
m = A.Var1(mask);
s = A.Var1(~mask);
```

**Output:**

```
>> m

m =

 5
10
16
25

>> s

s =

 0
 1
 2
 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
% Build a dummy txt data
txt = '';
for i=1:100
    txt = sprintf('%s%d metre\n%d sec\n',txt,2*i, i);
end

txt = regexprep(txt,'\n\n','\n')
data = sscanf(txt,'%d metre\n%d sec\n',[2 Inf])';
```

the `regexprep()` should take care of accidental double line breaks, while `sscanf()` parses the data in the right format.